# Remove rows that are too much alike not to be duplicates

Tags: python, data-cleaning

I have a [dataset of real estate advertisements](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XUjqeXVgjZJ8jVNAn9MeIb9zHLhVj4mwRs-hk1P050o/edit?usp=sharing). Several of the lines are about the same real estate property so it's full of duplicates that aren't exactly the same. What would be the best methods to remove rows that are too much alike not to be duplicates?

It looks like this :

```
    ID  URL CRAWL_SOURCE    PROPERTY_TYPE   NEW_BUILD   DESCRIPTION IMAGES  SURFACE LAND_SURFACE    BALCONY_SURFACE ... DEALER_NAME DEALER_TYPE CITY_ID CITY    ZIP_CODE    DEPT_CODE   PUBLICATION_START_DATE  PUBLICATION_END_DATE    LAST_CRAWL_DATE LAST_PRICE_DECREASE_DATE
0   22c05930-0eb5-11e7-b53d-bbead8ba43fe    http://www.avendrealouer.fr/location/levallois...   A_VENDRE_A_LOUER    APARTMENT   False   Au rez de chaussÃ©e d'un bel immeuble rÃ©cent,...   ["https://cf-medias.avendrealouer.fr/image/_87...   72.0    NaN NaN ... Lamirand Et Associes    AGENCY  54178039    Levallois-Perret    92300.0 92  2017-03-22T04:07:56.095 NaN 2017-04-21T18:52:35.733 NaN
1   8d092fa0-bb99-11e8-a7c9-852783b5a69d    https://www.bienici.com/annonce/ag440414-16547...   BIEN_ICI    APARTMENT   False   Je vous propose un appartement dans la rue Col...   ["http://photos.ubiflow.net/440414/165474561/p...   48.0    NaN NaN ... Proprietes Privees  MANDATARY   54178039    Levallois-Perret    92300.0 92  2018-09-18T11:04:44.461 NaN 2019-06-06T10:08:10.89  2018-09-25
```

So far I tried to compare the description :

```
df['is_duplicated'] = df.duplicated(['DESCRIPTION'])
```

And to compare the array of photos :

```
def image_similarity(imageAurls,imageBurls):
    imageAurls = ast.literal_eval(imageAurls)
    imageBurls = ast.literal_eval(imageBurls)
    for urlA in imageAurls:
        responseA = requests.get(urlA)
        imgA = Image.open(BytesIO(responseA.content))
        print(imgA)
        for urlB in imageBurls:
            responseB = requests.get(urlB)
            imgB = Image.open(BytesIO(responseB.content))    
            hash0 = imagehash.average_hash(imgA) 
            hash1 = imagehash.average_hash(imgB) 
            cutoff = 5

            if hash0 - hash1 < cutoff:
                print(urlA)
                print(urlB)
                return('similar')
        return('not similar')

df['NextImage'] = df['IMAGES'][df['IMAGES'].index - 1]
df['IsSimilar'] = df.apply(lambda x: image_similarity(x['IMAGES'], x['NextImage']), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into record linkage methods. They typically are used to find the same entity between two datasets but can also be used to link a dataset to itself and find duplicate records (it’s called deduplication in the literature)

Comment: That sounds like a great tool! Nevertheless, on this particular dataset, how will you advise me to use it? I'm running out of ideas for ways to detect its lines too similar to not be duplicates.